# Comparing hash values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

In my Ruby on Rails application i have the following params:

```
{"0"=>{"from_days"=>"1", "to_days"=>"2", "netto_price"=>"1.0", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"57"}, "1"=>{"from_days"=>"3", "to_days"=>"7", "netto_price"=>"23", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "2"=>{"from_days"=>"9", "to_days"=>"10", "netto_price"=>"123", "_destroy"=>"false"}}
```

Now i want to check that:

- 1[:from_days] > 0[:to_days]
- 2[:from_days] > 1[:to_days]
- etc.

Problem is that I want to do it dynamically because in future this parameters will grow up. Did anyone have idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
params = {"0"=>{"from_days"=>"1", "to_days"=>"2", "netto_price"=>"1.0", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"57"}, "1"=>{"from_days"=>"3", "to_days"=>"7", "netto_price"=>"23", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "2"=>{"from_days"=>"9", "to_days"=>"10", "netto_price"=>"123", "_destroy"=>"false"}}

(params.keys.min..params.keys.max).each do |index|
  if params[(index+1).to_s][:from_days].to_i > params[index.to_s][:to_days].to_i
    # your logic when 1[:from_days] > 0[:to_days] is true
  else

  end
end
```

This code implies that your `params` hash :

- must contain consecutive keys (no gap between each)
- must contain a hash having the `[:from_days]` AND the `[:to_days]` keys

Comment: Thanks for help but this code gave me the following error:
no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String

Comment: @MateuszUrbański I just updated my answer to add `.to_s` in `params[index.to_s]`

Comment: I tried the same soultion but still the same error.